# How can I carry out a titration to identify mercury in wastewater?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution

First, I would like to do a some form of extraction to only get the mercury, then followed by a titration to identify the concentration or the presence of mercury.

Comment: http://www.rdmag.com/news/2013/03/high-sensitivity-detection-method-found-mercury-water

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to determine the mercury content by titration? Atomic absorption spectroscopy, among other spectroscopic techniques, are likely simpler (so long as you have the instrument, of course), more precise, and more sensitive.

Comment: I'm confused about your question - how will you titrate to determine concentration/presence after you extract the mercury?

Answer (score 1):

The potentiometric titration of mercury with dithiooxamide has been successfully applied after preliminary separation of mercury by reduction (Comprehensive Water Analysis, Volume 2, pp.186-187, Elsevier).

Selective identification of mercury in waste water can be accomplished by fluorescence enhancement chemosensors (SENSOR LETTERS 2010, 8, 1–6). In this recent paper, the ﬂuorescent emission intensity of the probe is enhanced upon binding to mercury ions. The ﬂuorescence enhancement is attributed to a 1:1 complex formation between the probe and Hg(II) ion. The chemosensor can be applied for the quantiﬁcation of mercury; it shows a high selectivity toward Hg(II) ions in comparison with common metal ions.